# Динамическое изменение размера стека

Tags: gcc, стек, c, linux

Можно ли изменить (точнее - увеличить) в ходе выполнения программы объем памяти, доступной стеку? Linux, gcс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все. Сам разобрался.

Можно с помощью `setrlimit (RLIMIT_STACK, struct rlimit ...)`.